# Scheduled process to copy files out of S3 into a temp-folder in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, design-patterns, grep

Looking for recommendations for the following scenario:

In an ubuntu 18.04 server, every 1 minute check for new files in an AWS S3 bucket, fetch only the newest file to a temp folder at the end of the day remove them.

It should be automated in bash.

I proposed using aws s3 events notification, queues, lambda but it was defined that is best to keep it simple.

i am looking for recommendations for the steps described below:

For step 1 i was doing `aws s3 ls | awk (FUNCTION to filter files updated within the last minute)`
 then i realized that it was best to do it with `grep`

> ```
> 0-Cron job should run from 7:00 to 23:00 every minute     
> 1-List the files updated to S3 bucket during the past 1 minute
> 2-List the files in a temp-encrypted folder in ubuntu 18.03
> 3-Are the files listed in step 1 already downloaded in folder temp-encrypted from step 2
> 4-If the files are not already donloaded > download newest files from S3 bucket into temp-encrypted
> 5-At end of the day 23:00 take a record of the last files fetched from s3
> 6-run cleanup script at end of the day to remove everything in temp-encrypted
> ```

I attach a diagram with the intended process and infrastructure design.
[image: Intended process]

Comment: A few points:  You can `aws s3 sync` to copy any files from S3 not present locally.  You can do this every minute.  While it's wasteful, it's not much worse than listing the entire bucket to find new things, and easier.  I'd recommend, instead, using a SQS queue feed from an SNS topic that gets notified when new files are added to the bucket.  A script can then read the SQS queue to see what's new at any frequency you want.  Finally:  This is going to be *so* much easier in python, it's all possible in bash, but going to be a lot of extra work.

Comment: @Anon Coward thanks for your answer. That was my initial proposal so that bash script would only have to read from the queue with aws cli but appearantly it was going to take more time and now i am stuck. Also the possibility of having a log to track what was downloaded is to be considered.

Comment: I'd be curious how many files (about) are in this S3 bucket, how many are added a day, and if it's ever emptied.  For any sufficiently big bucket (10,000+ or so), I can't imagine trying to enumerate the contents every minute.  It'd work, but it's such overkill.  In many ways, this is why SQS exists, so you can offload the work.

Comment: i know every 28 days the bucket will be emptied because of the nature of the data.

Comment: Fair enough, so it's not completely unbounded.  Then I'd try writing something with `aws s3 sync` and see how far you get from there, unless I'm missing some nuance of why you can't sync down the bucket (or at least some prefix of it) and keep everything locally for those 28 days.

Comment: i will double check because i think is ok to sync but the files must be encrypted on the fly...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was like this:

1. Change FTPS to SFTP running in Ubuntu 18.04
2. change main ports: randomport1 for SSH and randomport2 for SFTP
3. configure SFTP in sshd_config file
4. once everything is working create local directory structure
5. by using a bash script

5.1 List what is in S3 and save in a var

5.2 for each of the files listed in s3 check if there is a new file not present in the mirrored file in the local directory s3-mirror

5.3 if there is new file fetch, touch a file with empy contents in s3-mirror directory just same name, move encrypted file to SFTP and remove fetched S3 file from mirrored local directory

5.4 record successful actions in a log.

So far it works good.